# Setting values on a child bean

Tags: java, spring

I would like to get a child object in my Spring IoC application context and set a value on it. How can I do this?

Here is the code equivalent:

```
// The constructor here instantiates the correct child object
MyContainerBean container = new MyContainerBean();
container.getChild().setValue(someValue);
```

Comment: Are you asking if `someValue` can be injected by the application context?

Comment: In what context? Spring? Something else? You've provided almost no information that someone could use to understand your question.

Comment: @Jim - Yes, in the Spring application context.

Comment: @Jeremy - Yes, I would like to inject someValue in the application context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean

```
<bean id="container" class="MyContainerBean">
    <property name="child">
        <bean class="Child">
            <property name="value" value="someValue"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

?

**Edit:** Based on your response, your problem is that you have a violation of Inversion of Control. Objects don't create their own dependencies. They allow them to be injected. The best you can do with XML configuration in this case would probably be to create the container, inject it into some object, and have that object make the changes you need. You could also use [Java-based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) to create and configure the container bean as needed.

Comment: This is somewhat like what I am looking for. The difference is I am unable to instantiate Child in the bean. The default constructor for MyContainer instantiates Child. Then, I would like to get the Child object which MyContainer instantiated and set a value on it.

Comment: What prevents you from using Spring to instantiate the child?

Comment: The parent itself constructs the child and provides its own default values to the child's constructor. I don't want to interfere with that part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent instantiates the child and you can't change that, then inject the value into the parent and have the parent inject it into the child at the appropriate moment.  If the value to be injected isn't known at parent creation time then you have to change the design.